# write data structure with write function

Tags: c, posix

My note is that the second parameter of the write function is mostly a string. I would like to know if it is possible to send a data structure (example: struct sockaddr_in) to the second parameter to put it in a buffer with write , then use it after reading this buffer to get the starting element.

how can we use in the context of swapped memory and pipes ?

example  :

```
    struct ess
{
    int valeur ;

    char indice ;

    char* description ;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct ess *exemple ;

    exemple = (struct ess*)malloc((size_t)sizeof(struct ess)) ;

    exemple->val = 125 ;

    exemple->indice = 'o' ;

    exemple->description = "valeur adéquate" ;

    //Ecriture dans un tampon

    char *buffer ;

    buffer = (char*)malloc((size_t)sizeof(*exemple)) ;

    memmove(buffer , &(*exemple) , (size_t)sizeof(exemple)) ;

    struct ess *esi ;

    esi = (struct ess*)malloc((size_t)sizeof(struct ess)) ;

    memmove(&(*esi) , buffer , (size_t)sizeof(*esi)) ;

    printf("%s\n",esi->description );

    return 0;
}
```

There is segmentation error

Comment: You can do `write(fd, &addr, sizeof addr)`, `memmove(buffer, &addr, sizeof addr)`, `read(fd, &addr, sizeof addr)`, and `memmove(&addr, buffer, sizeof addr)`. If you used a socket pair (say, Unix domain datagram socket pair) instead of a pipe, you could even pass the descriptor (connected and/or bound to a socket address of any type; or open to a file, character device, block device, or pipe) as an ancillary message. How about you describe the underlying problem you're trying to solve instead?

Comment: and it will be the same for other data structures ??

Comment: Yes, you can do that for all data structures. Do note that if the structure contains a pointer, only the value of the pointer is transferred; and because each process has their own address space, the pointer value is basically useless. So, in practice, you could say *"it works for all structures, but isn't useful for any pointer members"*. (Socket address structures do not contain pointers.)

Comment: Another point where it is not applicable, if you want to read the file on a different machine.  Especially if the writing machine is big endian and the reading machine is little endian or vice versa.

Comment: If I decide to use memmove, will there not be a segmentation error?

Comment: IIUC, you need memcpy(), not memmove. [and most/all of your copies are not needed at all]

Comment: can this function be used in inter-process communication with pipes , socket , swapping memory , ....?